# Does Firebase Storage support Load Balancing(/GoogleCDN/CloudArmor)? Because of the security rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, load-balancing

Hi short important question:

Like much people I want to use the [Load Balancing + Cloud CDN + Cloud Armor stack](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/networking/using-cloud-armor-and-cloud-cdn-with-your-google-load-balancer). Because yeah, CDN and anti DDOS is important. Load Balancing too.

Cloud Storage is supported by Load Balancing of course. But now the question is: Is Firebase Storage supported too (i think yes because it's basically the same, but Firebase Storage has important features like security rules, are they supported too)? Especially: Will the security rules still work? Because Firebase Storage is built on top of Cloud Storage. I have fear that Load Balancing points to the Cloud Storage Bucket instead of the Firebase Storage skin; and therefore the security rules won't work anymore of course.

Thanks in advance!

Second question: When it comes to uploading, is it possible to set up Load Balancing in this process too? I want that e.g Indian users upload their data to an indian bucket instead of an US bucket.